# How can I export Wordpress post content into csv with <p> and <br>?

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, export-to-csv

I'm using the WP All Export plugin to create custom exports of my posts into CSV. However, none of the post content has `<p>` or `<br>` tags, it's just white spaces. I need the tags because I'm importing into a different type of CMS that doesn't treat white space as breaks.

I played around with adding and removing the following in functions.php:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

But that only shows the tags within the WYSIWYG editor. The content in the database has white space. Is there a PHP function I can run on my export to include the P and BR tags on my content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<?php echo apply_filters( 'filter_name', $body ); ?>`

You could use the_content filter or your own custom filter.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/

In functions.php:

`add_filter( 'custom_filter_name', 'wpautop');`
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/

Comment: The WP All Export plugin allowed me to add in a function passing $value of the content i needed:

    `<?php
    echo wpautop( $value );
    ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following the [accepted answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6844/how-do-i-add-paragraph-tags-to-all-of-my-posts-after-relying-on-wpauto) which works even thought it says it's untested.

**Backup that database first though!**

Add the code to your themes active `functions.php` and click any link in the Wordpress backend.  The code will run.  Then delete the code from `functions.php`.

This will update the content in the database with the paragraph tags normally used to output to screen.  When you run the export, you'll have the tags in your .csv